# Add data-toggle to image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How does the syntax go if I want to do something like `data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!"` but for my image_tag. I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with my syntax.

My attempt:

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/info.svg",:class=>"infoicon"), :options => { :data => {toggle => "tooltip"},:title => "my caption"  %>
```

The error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

I have the following js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Update:
I tried using (since I missed an (}) in the image_tag above)

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/info.svg",:class=>"infoicon"), :options => { :data => {toggle => "tooltip"},:title => "my caption" } %>
```

but still the same error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image_tag is defined as:

```
image_tag(source, options = {})
```

So you could try using your class, data and title as the options argument of the image_tag helper, like:

```
<%= image_tag '/assets/info.svg', class: 'infoicon', data: { toggle: 'tooltip' }, title: 'my caption' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked. I'm curious what was wrong with my syntax? I don't understand why it did not work.

Comment: Glad to help,you had some extra parenthesis, missing a `:` in toggle, and that you were wrapping data and title inside the options key.